# Change all the buttons color in java

Tags: java

I have 20 Buttons and i want change the color of the all the buttons when i click on a special button, is there any way to do this with function(or without function) and do not using setBackground for 20 times

Comment: Why not use a loop?

Comment: `"and do not using setBackground for 20 times"` -- please justify this statement. The proper thing to do is as @ItamarGreen states, to place all the buttons within a collection such as an ArrayList and, yes, make 20 `setBackground(...)` calls but from within the loop.

Comment: Your statement in fact suggests that you may be putting the cart before the horse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the buttons in an array

```
JButton[] array = new JButton[20];
//then add the buttons to the array
```

Then:

```
for(JButton button : array){
    button.setBackground(/*the color you want*/);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not do `button1`, `button2`, etc.

Instead, make a `List<Button> buttons`. You'll still have to call `add()` 20 times on that list, but then you can loop over them all.

```
for (Button b : buttons) {
    b.setBackground(color);
}
```